# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Dynamically set CORS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, cors

In my MVC5 application, I've a controller that can be called from client applications (AngularJs in my case) and returns JSON.
For this particular Controller/Action, I want to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin dynamically, depending of the "client_id" params in QueryString.

My problem is that I can't find a way to handle the Http Options request from the browser...

I've try many solutions:

**1- [HttpOptions] Attribute on top of the Action Controller**:
The code is never executed called

```
[HttpOptions]
public virtual ActionResult Refresh(string client_id)
{
     // This code is never executed
     // Should be setting CORS depending on the client_id
}

[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Refresh(string client_id, FormCollection form)
{
     // This is executed after the browser Http Options Request
}
```

**2- Create my own ActionFilter, and put the CORS Headers from this filter**: Never handle the Http Options Request.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ApplicationCrossOriginAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // This code is never executed on Http Options Request
        // Set custom CORS header here on Http Options Request
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**3- Use Global.asax Application_BeginRequest Event**: Once again, the code is never reach with an Http Options Request...

I've so tried to simply configure CORS from the Web.config file, but I don't want to hardcode the Origins (and I can't since it's all domains are dynamic...)
But, yeah, everything works perfectly with this configuration:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <clear/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /><!--Not dynamic here-->
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Accept,Authorization" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

I'm stuck here, as i don't know how to fill my needs...

Comment: I think it does not make sense to dynamically set CORS based on "client_id". Just do a normal authorization based on the "client_id"

Comment: What I want to do may have no sense, but i want to only allow origin to the domain bind with the client_id.

Comment: You have to configure the entire pipiline to accept cors, not just this only client connection. If you are behind OWIN you should configure It directly there.

Comment: Can you be more explicit ? I'm not using Owin, it's a basic MVC 5 application, nothing special.

Comment: Edit: everyting works well with the web.config CORS, but I really want to set CORS according to the client_id, and I don't understand why it's not possible ><'